# How to stop repeating lotti animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here I'm trying to create a order completion popup screen. but the [done] animation repeating all the time, i want to stop that after completing the complete frame of the animation.
here is my screen

[image]

and how can i achieve this, if my question is not clear please comment

Comment: Please post the code corresponding to your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LottieBuilder.asset(
            'assets/animations/gpay_check.json',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            repeat: false,              // add this line
            controller: lottieController,
),
```